# Drog and Drop TableLayoutPanel in a panel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop

I'm trying a drag and drop for a tablelayoutpanel in a panel using winforms/c#, the drag of the tablelayout works successfully but the problem is that the tablelayoutpanel droped doesn't appear !! 
any solution please ??

```
private void Registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
     panel2.AllowDrop = true;
     tableLayoutPanel1.AllowDrop = true;
     panel2.DragEnter += panel2_DragEnter;   
     panel2.DragDrop += panel2_DragDrop;
     tableLayoutPanel1.MouseDown += tableLayoutPanel1_MouseDown;
}   

private void panel2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     ((TableLayoutPanel)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TableLayoutPanel))).Parent (Panel)sender;                
}
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     tableLayoutPanel1.DoDragDrop(tableLayoutPanel1, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is inadequate, you'll need to at least set the Location property of the dropped TLP to ensure it is within the panel bounds and/or located at the mouse cursor.  And the Z-order matters, setting the Parent property puts it at the bottom so it can easily be overlapped by other controls in the panel, you need BringToFront().

Try this:

```
    private void panel2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TableLayoutPanel))) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        var tlp = (TableLayoutPanel)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TableLayoutPanel));
        tlp.Location = panel2.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        tlp.Parent = panel2;
        tlp.BringToFront();
    }
```

Comment: please how can I save the new location definitly of the TLP after the Drag and Drop ?